# Server session handle in multiple browsers in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

My asp.net session objects are storing in SQL server.I am storing an `ID` in session. If client open another browser and storing different `ID` in session. I need to notify client is  “are you sure you want both ID’s open?” in same based user logged user.

Application runs on logged in user (not anonymous)

How can we check this in asp.net?

Comment: How do you propose to know that it's the same client who already has a window open, and not a new person coming to the site?

Comment: With login id I will know, Who logged in.

Comment: You might want to expand upon your question by editing it to explain that people are logging in, so that you know that information. Otherwise it reads as if you are asking about anonymous users opening new windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to go about this:

Option #1, in your user table, add a value called "session id"

When a user logs in, check to see what their last session id was.  Then test to see if it's still a valid session.  If it is, ask them what they want to do.  Store the latest session id in that table after each log in.

However, I'd go with option #2: Don't do this.  If the user wants to open multiple browser windows to access your application then let them.  There's probably a pretty good reason for it.  Most (as in nearly all) users have no idea what "session state" even means and they really have no desire to know.  All they care about is getting their job done.

Comment: your option #2 is "what" and not "how" - OP is asking how to handle situation when each single user can have multiple sessions. For teh same reason, option #1 is not going to work well either - you can't access information in another session unless you do session hijacking of some way. I do believe that in the OP's case the only right way to store temp data is using some sort of cache

Answer (score 4):

Session is not linked to an authenticated user, and there is no way of accessing an other connection's Session without knowing its SessionID.

Usually this kind of problem can be solved using cache instead of session state. With cache you can create your own user-based keys to store data. Depending on whether you are planning to just run your web app on one server or in a web farm environment, you can either use asp.net in-process cache or one of numerous distributed cache solutions (like memcached which I'm using in my web projects with great success).